# Which Robot for ROS?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

which of the supported robots would you recommend for using with ROS (educational purposes)? Turtlebot seems to lead the way but are there any real alternatives? Anything that comes close to Turtlebot (and is in the same/similar price range)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12822/which-robot-for-ros?/) by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 345 on 2012-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would say that the Turtlebot is the most well-supported platform on these forums, just out of experience. That is not to say that other robots aren't well-supported, but there are lots of tutorials and help for Turtlebot users. I'm not sure of any other robots really in that price range.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2012-01-31**:
Additionally, I will add that the TurtleBot  has a growing community with over 450 official TurtleBots sold and about 100 more homemade robots (even Bilibot is using the TurtleBot stacks as a basis). Many professors have already started creating curriculum around the TurtleBot that you could use.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [Bilibot](http://www.bilibot.com/) platform offers similar features to the Turtlebot and has an integrated "powerboard" that allows for a single charger.  I believe the Turtlebot requires separate chargers for the computer and the iRobot Create, whereas the Bilibot has one plug to power/charge the create and the main computer supply.  It also has Intel i3 processor that's a bit beefier than the dual-atom you get in the Turtlebot's netbook.  Plus it ships with an arm (albeit very limited).

Unfortunately, other than basic setup instructions the documentation/tutorials for the Bilibot platform are severely lacking.  As a contributing member of the project, I'm working with my local university to help find and fix some holes in that area over the upcoming semester (they purchased a number of them as general-purpose ROS machines).

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2012-01-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just built my own basically-a-turtlebot with a netbook, an iRobot Create, and a kinect. It's not as 100% pretty, but it works well.

Basically [this](http://murph.cc/isaac/), but the latest one uses a turtlebot power board instead of the handmade one since it included a gyro that I needed.

---

Originally posted by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) with karma: 1033 on 2012-01-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-01-31**:
I too have gone the "build my own turtlebot workalike" route, as have many others. It works quite well.